# Table schema changes sometimes

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2012

We use SQL Server and ADO in Delphi and we are creating temporary tables for use with a report program.

The program flow is like this :

1. Create a table with a SQL query "create table"
2. Write data in table.
3. Drop table via SQL query.

It usually works, but some customers regularly complain that "drop table" fails with error "invalid object name".

I could get remote access to the customers database, and I saw following :

- the table X is shown in the table listing (by Delphi)
- in Delphi, the table cannot be opened or deleted.
- the table schema is "Server\1" instead of "dbo"!

How could the table schema of this table change, and how should I handle this issue? Why does it work sometimes, and sometimes not?

Comment: Better use temp tables (e.g #TempTable) instead of creating temp tables in the dbo schema.

Comment: (1) If you create table without explicitly specifying schema, a default will be assigned. (2) The default differs depending on which user you're logged in as at the time you create the table. **Solution** Simply be explicit.

Comment: Since we have a very large code base, it will be very hard to change every SQL-query to have a `[dbo]` prefix. However, I could search and find all occurences of "CREATE TABLE" and change these. Will this work? (CREATE TABLE uses dbo prefix, and INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT, DROP use no schema prefix?)

Comment: Since a table exists with "Server\1" schema, you can guarantee it wasn't created using "dbo" prefix. So you may want to double-check your existing `CREATE TABLE` statements. (Though the table may have been created with an older version of your code.) Secondly, `INSERT UPDATE DELETE` are different: if no schema is specified, it will first try user's default, then fallback to dbo if the object isn't found. (Note this might also apply to `DROP`, I'm not 100% sure - reads the docs.)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using temporary tables and keeping all related code in SQL.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#YourTable') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ##YourTable; -- just a precaution if it's already there

SELECT <field list>
into #YourTable -- this creates a the table with the structure of the "select" dataset
from YourSource_table
join Another_table on <join conditions>
where <your selection conditions>;
```

In a separate query read data from your temporary table

```
SELECT <field list> from #YourTable;
```

Make your report.
When all done, drop temporary table

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#YourTable') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ##YourTable;
```

Temporary tables accessible inside a single session; that means you must ensure you created it and read from the same connection component and keep it open in between. Other users won't see them (MS SQL server adds a unique suffix to its name)

Comment: Temporary tables siund interesting, and I might use them in other contexts sometime. However, it probably won't work in this case, because the data providing application, and the report software (crystal reports) are 2 different programs, which do not share a connection. (or maybe I didn't found that feature yet)

Comment: You may use global temporary tables. The syntax is similar, just change single hash to double hash, like ##YourTempTable. You must be sure only one user calls your report at a time, otherwise you may get funny results.